# Need to generate separate CMYK images in color from PDF

Tags: pdf, printing, imagemagick, ghostscript

Several months ago, a decommissioned Solaris 5.6 box died at work before I could get a backup of it. One of this machine's primary purposes when it was in production involved taking a PDF (v1.3), generating separate Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and Black images, and displaying those images in a simple web page. This box had been decommissioned 18 months prior, but it was still on. I now have a need to reproduce this capability on a modern linux box.

I've tried

```
 gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=tiffsep -sOutputFile=CMYK-%d.pdf CMYKPDF.pdf
```

This is the closest I've gotten to outputting separate color images, but the outputs are gray, indicating how much ink should be deposited. I would like to have the output pictures in Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and Black, not their respective greyscale counterparts.

Imagemagick seemed promising but I didn't see how to generate separate CMYK images with that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with CMYK and printing industry terminology and technology, and I am happy to be told I am wrong if someone can tell me better and we can all learn....

Anyway, I think that the CMYK separation done by ImageMagick does not do *"Minimum Black"* - a technique, I believe, to minimise volume of ink on paper by reducing CMY components to a minimum and replacing as much as possible with black ink. So an ImageMagick separation may look different from what real printers might expect. So I think your ghostscript version is maybe preferable. You can however, use ImageMagick to colour in your separations, so in your example you could do:

```
convert CMYK-1.pdf(Cyan).tif    +level-colors cyan,    cyan.tif
convert CMYK-1.pdf(Magenta).tif +level-colors magenta, magenta.tif
convert CMYK-1.pdf(Yellow).tif  +level-colors yellow,  yellow.tif
```

If you use those commands, the separations for this page look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to try the ImageMagick separation, you would do something like this:

```
convert document.pdf -colorspace CMYK -separate plate%d.png
```

which will give you `plate0.png` with the Cyan plate, `plate1.png` with the Magenta plate, `plate2.png` with the Yellow plate and `plate3.png` with the Black. Of course, you can colour these in the same as I showed above for your ghostscript-generated separations.

Comment: "Minimum black" is commonly referred to as either TAC-reduction or "Ink saving". It generally isn't part of the process of simply generating separated images from a CMYK file and the use of it in production varies greatly (as it has a serious effect on what the printer needs to do to print your files afterwards). (What you're saying is far from wrong, just thought I'd add that comment).

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche Thank you for your insight - I am always happy to learn.

Comment: My apologies, for I can only upvote once. This worked wonders.

Comment: PS, I'm also using the `montage` program in ImageMagick to to stitch these CMYK separations together side by side. Thanks again.